# Calculate the count of a status on a previous date

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a measure that will count the number of items in a particular state in a past period of time.

I have the following table:

| ID | Created Date | Breached Date | Resolved Date | Status | Breached |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | 1/7/2020 | 2/2/2020 | Complete | TRUE |
| 2 | 1/1/2020 | 2/9/2020 | - | Active | TRUE |
| 3 | 1/5/2020 | - | - | Active | FALSE |
| 4 | 1/15/2020 | 2/9/2020 | - | Active | TRUE |
| 5 | 2/2/2020 | - | 2/12/2020 | Complete | FALSE |
| 6 | 2/4/2020 | - | 2/4/2020 | Complete | FALSE |
| 7 | 2/15/2020 | 2/15/2020 | - | Complete | TRUE |
| 8 | 3/7/2020 | 4/27/2020 | 4/28/2020 | Complete | TRUE |
| 9 | 3/9/2020 | - | 4/13/2020 | Complete | FALSE |
| 10 | 3/9/2020 | 4/20/2020 | 4/18/2020 | Complete | TRUE |

I want to know: for any month, at the beginning of the month, how many tickets were in an active status and have a breached status of TRUE. This number would not include items from that month, only previous months.

The expected output for the table above:
|  ID |  January  |  February  |   March  |   April   |    May    |
|:---:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|
|  1  |     F     |     T     |     F     |     F     |     F     |
|  2  |     F     |     F     |     T     |     T     |     T     |
|  3  |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |
|  4  |     F     |     F     |     T     |     T     |     T     |
|  5  |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |
|  6  |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |
|  7  |     F     |     F     |     T     |     T     |     T     |
|  8  |     F     |     F     |     T     |     F     |     F     |
|  9  |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |     F     |
|  10 |     F     |     F     |     F     |     T     |     F     |
|Total|     0     |     1     |     4     |     4     |     3     |

I think it's as easy as:
Count ID 
If Breached is less then month and resolved is less then month

How do I make this into a measure so that I can apply a month filter to it?